# Extracting data between two delimiters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a column that contains data in the format of **aaa|bbb|ccc** and need to extract aaa, bbb & ccc from the data separately.

I tried

```
SELECT  
    SUBSTRING(Column1, 0, CHARINDEX('|', Column1)) AS [First],
    SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('|', Column1)  + 1, LEN(Column1)) AS [Second]
FROM
    Table1
```

OUTPUT:

```
aaa [FIRST],bbb|ccc [Second]
```

but I need `aaa [FIRST],bbb [Second],ccc [Third]`

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  If you're using SQL Server 2016 or newer you can use the STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: @squillman I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: You can use a string splitting function. Here's [Jeff Moden's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). Here's [my modified version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenHibble/T-SQL-Tools/master/SplitString.sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string that are exactly same format (three times) delimited by `|` then you can [PARSENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
select col1, parsename(cols, 3) fisrt, parsename(cols, 2) second, parsename(cols, 1) third
from table1 t1 cross apply
     ( values (replace(col1, '|', '.')) 
     ) t2 (cols);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time and it works well for me:

```
DECLARE @delimString VARCHAR(255) = 'aaa|bbb|ccc';

DECLARE @xml XML = '<val>' + REPLACE( @delimString, '|', '</val><val>' ) + '</val>'

SELECT 
    x.f.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) AS val
FROM @xml.nodes( '//val' ) x( f );
```

Returns

```
+-----+
| val |
+-----+
| aaa |
| bbb |
| ccc |
+-----+
```

If you're looking for a columnar return and know you will always **only** have three values to parse, you might be able to get away with something like the below example. You can run it in SSMS.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( [value] VARCHAR(255) );
INSERT INTO @table ( [value] ) VALUES 
( 'aaa|bbb|ccc' )
, ( '0A-PRDS|JQLM-1|1967' )
, ( 'J1658|G-1|2003' );

SELECT
    [value]
    , SUBSTRING( [value], 0, CHARINDEX( '|', [value] ) ) AS Column1
    , SUBSTRING( 
        [value]
        , ( CHARINDEX( '|', [value]) + 1 )  -- starting position of column 2.
        , CHARINDEX( '|', [value],  ( CHARINDEX( '|', [value] ) + 1 ) ) - ( CHARINDEX( '|', [value]) + 1 ) -- length of column two is the number of characters between the two delimiters.
    ) AS Column2
    , SUBSTRING(
        [value]
        , CHARINDEX( '|', [value], ( CHARINDEX( '|', [value] ) + 1 ) ) + 1
        , LEN( [value] )
    ) AS Column3
FROM @table;
```

Returns

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|        value        | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| aaa|bbb|ccc         | aaa     | bbb     | ccc     |
| 0A-PRDS|JQLM-1|1967 | 0A-PRDS | JQLM-1  | 1967    |
| J1658|G-1|2003      | J1658   | G-1     | 2003    |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: The Column1 & Column3 works perfectly but Column2 is not getting expected results for example strings like '0A-PRDS|JQLM-1|1967 Phase One Request'  and  'J1658|G-1|2003 Phase three Request'

Comment: You are correct. I have updated my example accordingly. In your case, PARSENAME seems to be the least complicated way of getting what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way where function `charindex`,`SUBSTRING` and `REVERSE` used

```
 with t as (select 'aaa|bbb|ccc' as val)
select t.*,
       LEFT(val, charindex('|', val) - 1),
   SUBSTRING(val, charindex('|', val)+1, len(val) - CHARINDEX('|', reverse(val)) - charindex('|', val)),
       REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(val), charindex('|', reverse(val)) - 1))
from t;

val             
aaa|bbb|ccc     aaa     bbb     ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the value in the column using a common table expression (CTE) since split function is not available in your version of SQL Server

```
WITH CTE(userString,startIndex,EndIndex)
AS
(
    SELECT Column1,1,CHARINDEX('|',Column1)
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Column1, EndIndex+1,CHARINDEX('|',Column1,EndIndex+1)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE EndIndex !=0 
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(userString,
                startIndex,
                CASE WHEN EndIndex > 0 
                THEN EndIndex - startIndex ELSE LEN(Column1) END) 
       as splitVALUES
FROM CTE
```